# How do I solve Check the render method of Header in my react App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm trying to create a e-commerce web app by following an online tutorial on Udemy but I have run into an error that I cannot seem to fix even though I have done everything the tutorial has done and theirs is working fine.

The error I am getting is telling me to **Check the render method of Header**

Which I have done and it is the same as the working tutorial.

This is my index.js file where the error is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And this is my header component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../../assets/crown.svg';

import './header.styles.scss';


const Header = () => (
    <div className="header">
        <Link className="logo-container" to="/">
            <Logo className="logo" />
        </Link>
        <div className="options">
            <Link className="option" to="/shop">SHOP</Link>
            <Link className="signin" to="/shop">SIGN IN</Link>
            <Link className="option" to="/contact">CONTACT</Link>
        </div>
    </div>
)

export default Header;
```

This is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

import HomePage from './pages/homepage/homepage.component';
import ShopPage from './pages/shop/shop.component';
import SignInSignUpPage from  './components/sign-in-sign-up/sign-in-sign-up.component';
import Header from  './components/header/header.component';
import { auth } from './firebase/firebase.utils';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      currentUser: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ currentUser: user });
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
         <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
          <Route path='/shop' component={ShopPage} />
          <Route path='/signin' component={SignInSignUpPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I can not seem to figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: @Andy That's not suspicious, since many bundler configurations automagically transform those into real modules.

Comment: Anyway, please show the full error, not just that last line "Check the render method of Header".

Answer (score 0):

Got a floating period in here...

`<Link className="option". to="/contact">CONTACT</Link>`

Comment: My mistake, thats just a typo. It is not in my actual code

Comment: Show us your `App.js` file please

Comment: Ive added in the App.js file

Comment: How about that ReactComponent, what's going on inside of there?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: ‘ import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../../assets/crown.svg';’

Comment: that is to import a logo from a svg file and use it in the navigation bar.

Comment: I've copied/pasted your code into codesandbox (without your other files etc), I do not see an issue. My comment about the Logo file was maybe there's something there that we don't see. What browser are you using? Did you try a hard refresh? I don't know why you are getting this error because it looks good on my end.

Comment: yes i tried everything and nothing worked so i just created a new react project and copied what i have done from the old project to the new projects and it is all working now.

Comment: "Did you turn it off and on again?"

Comment: turn what off and on?

Comment: It's a reference to the IT Crowd, tongue in cheek.  When nothing makes sense you turn it off and on again.  We've all been there, glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the help